# Lightswitch field is read-only altough it is not computed or calculated in SQL, why?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Lightswitch field is read-only  altough  it is not computed or calculated in SQL, why?

How can I chack why it is read-only...

Comment: Just one property in an entity? Or all properties in an entity?

Does the entity have an integer PK (primary key)?

Is this a table in the intrinsic database (LS), or in an external data source (SQL)?

Comment: Hi, not all properties in entity. Yes, entity has PK (guid), and this table is in external data source - SQL 2008. That property is not an foreign key, and it is not computed, neither identity...?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it is not a computed property in Lightswitch. But does it default to the output of a function in SQL? Has it _ever_ been set to a function or an identity? I had an issue where I changed the type in SQL but the field remained read-only in Lightswitch.

Comment: So all of the rest of the properties are able to be edited? And it's just this one property that can't be edited? It's not the entity's PK is it? Because that will always be read-only. You can't set PK/FK's manually. I can't think of any other reason why just one property in an entity would be read-only. The only reasons that I know of that cause a read-only property is; it's the PK, or the entity is a SQL View. Is this column able to be edited in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)? I can't help but feel that the answer relies on something that you haven't told us yet, but I can't think what.

Comment: That property is not PK. And is never be set to a function. But it was an identity in SQL! Is that a reason. (I remove identity now in SQL); and if it is, how can I reverse that in Lightswitch?